# trim all strings in an array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, trim

I have a string that comes in like:

```
string email = "a@a.com, b@b.com, c@c.com";
```

I want to split it into an array of strings

If I do this:

```
string[] emails = email.Split(',');
```

I get spaces in front of each email address (after the first one):

```
emails[0] = "a@a.com"
emails[1] = " b@b.com"
emails[2] = " c@c.com"
```

What is the best way to get this (either a better way to parse or a way to trim all strings in an array)?

```
emails[0] = "a@a.com"
emails[1] = "b@b.com"
emails[2] = "c@c.com"
```

Comment: If the space will _always_ be there, you could add it to the split... ie: email.Split(', ');

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could also replace all occurrences of spaces, and so avoid the foreach loop:

```
string email = "a@a.com, b@b.com, c@c.com";    
string[] emails = email.Replace(" ", "").Split(',');
```

Comment: Works ok for this specific example, but doesn't maintain spaces for the resultant elements like; "foo bar, another element, blah_blah". Bryan Watts has the best answer IMO.

Comment: Hi @revgum! That's true, but I have sticked to comply @leora's requirements. The example you´re describing, IMO, is outside the context of this question. Thanks anyway for your feedback.

Comment: -1 I agree that this is not a good thing to do. Buyer beware.

Comment: also downvoted. i agree that the answer does the trick, but Bryans answer is more useful in general

Comment: This isn't right. It will not trim, but remove spaces from strings in array, which is totally different from trim (removing trailing and leading spaces)

Answer (score 264):

```
emails.Split(',').Select(email => email.Trim()).ToArray()
```

Comment: @Moismyname: I'm not sure what constraint would lead you down that path, but there are other answers that address your question.

Comment: First: very nice solution ! Regarding the question of the OP shouldn't  it be `email.Split(...)...` instead of `emails.Split(..)...` ? I think emails is already the split array.

Comment: @klaas: Indeed you are correct, I hadn't noticed before. In isolation the answer reads well (enough to have garnered a few votes :-) ), so I'll likely keep it intact.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer, as the question was to TRIM each string, not necessarily replace spaces with blanks.

Comment: what if some element is null

Comment: @IrfanUllah: Chain a `.Where(email => email != null)`

Comment: Interesting solution. Can someone explain what's being done here? Is `Select(email => email.Trim())` a function call on a `string[]` (the result of `Split()`)?

Comment: @MinhTran It is indeed a function call - `Select` is a family of extension methods that make up LINQ in the `System.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 23):

Either one of the following would work. I'd recommend the first since it more accurately expresses the joining string.

```
string[] emails = email.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string[] emails = email.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know about the options. Coming from Perl I see regexs everywhere. With the options Split is the way to go.

Comment: +1 we use LINQ so much that we tend to forget that other elegant options do exist.

Comment: In this specific case, email addresses can't have spaces, so I would use the second option.

Answer (score 11):

You can use Trim():

```
string email = "a@a.com, b@b.com, c@c.com";
string[] emails = email.Split(',');
emails = (from e in emails
          select e.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Comment: This answer is correct but is overkill, this answer has the best approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355704/trim-all-strings-in-an-array/1355732#1355732

Answer (score 8):

Use `Regex.Split` to avoid trimming

```
var emails = Regex.Split(email, @",\s*");
```

Answer (score 7):

.NET 5 has arrived and with it, a modern solution to this problem:

```
string[] emails = email.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
```

Comment: This should be considered as the best option, as it's more perf than any other answer here

Answer (score 5):

You can use a one line solution like this:

```
string[] emails = text.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Array.ForEach<string>(emails, x => emails[Array.IndexOf<string>(emails, x)] = x.Trim());
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to manipulate the entries, without returning the array:

```
string[] emails = text.Split(',');
Array.ForEach(emails, e => e.Trim());
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can split using a regular expression of the form:

```
\s*,\s*
```

i.e.

```
string[] emails = Regex.Split(email, @"\s*,\s*");
```

It will consume the surrounding spaces directly.

Regular expressions are usually a performance hit, but the example you gave indicates that this is something you plan to do once in your code for a short array.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Bryan Watts is elegant and simple. He implicitly refers to the array of strings created by the Split().

Also note its extensibility if you are reading a file, and want to massage the data while building an array.

```
string sFileA = @"C:\Documents and Settings\FileA.txt";
string sFileB = @"C:\Documents and Settings\FileB.txt";

// Trim extraneous spaces from the first file's data
string[] fileAData = (from line in File.ReadAllLines( sFileA )
                      select line.Trim()).ToArray();

// Strip a second unneeded column from the second file's data
string[] fileBData = (from line in File.ReadAllLines( sFileB )
                      select line.Substring( 0, 21 ).Trim()).ToArray();
```

Of course, you can use the Linq => notation if you prefer.

```
string[] fileBData = File.ReadAllLines( sFileB ).Select( line =>
                             line.Substring( 0, 21 ).Trim()).ToArray();
```

Although my answer should have been posted as a comment, I don't have enough reputation points to comment yet. But I found this discussion invaluable in figuring out how to massage data while using ReadAllLines().

Comment: Wecome to [SO].  One small point on your code: If you're using Linq like that, you might be better using `File.ReadLines`.  `ReadAllLines` "slurps" the entire file into an array in memory, which can obviously be problematic with big files.  `ReadLines` only reads one line at a time, which is great if you don't need to keep the initial version of the contents.

Comment: Thanks! I can see that the example using ReadAllLines will break down for very large files, containing both the raw data and the trimmed versions in memory at the same time, for a moment. The documentation page for File.ReadLines() also has an example that fits in with this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Trim` in a `foreach` loop, or if you are using .NET 3.5+ a LINQ statement.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 5, they added [`StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=net-6.0#system-stringsplitoptions-trimentries).

You can use it like

```
string[] emails = email.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
```

Which will give you

```
emails[0] = "a@a.com"
emails[1] = "b@b.com"
emails[2] = "c@c.com"
```